# Create column and insert into it within the same transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, alter-table

Is it possible to create a column and insert values to it during the same transaction? This is part of an upgrade script. I found the following method [online](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1467/populate-a-sql-server-column-with-a-sequential-number-not-using-an-identity/), but it does not work; I get an error: `Invalid column name 'IndexNumber'.`. I'm assuming this is because the transaction hasn't created the column yet so there is nothing to insert to.

The relevant parts of my script:

```
Print 'Beginning Upgrade'
Begin Transaction
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------
    USE [MyDatabase];

    /* Widgets now can be ordered and the order can be modified */
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ADD [IndexNumber] [int] NULL;

    DECLARE @ind INT 
    SET @ind = 0 
    UPDATE [dbo].[Widgets]
    SET @ind = [IndexNumber] = @ind + 1;

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ALTER COLUMN [IndexNumber] [int] NOT NULL;
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------
Commit tran
Print 'Upgrade completed'
```

The reason why `[IndexNumber]` is not an identity column is that it must be editable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Another alternative, if you don't want to split the code into separate batches, is to use [`EXEC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to create a nested scope/batch:

```
Print 'Beginning Upgrade'
Begin Transaction
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------
    USE [MyDatabase];

    /* Widgets now can be ordered and the order can be modified */
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ADD [IndexNumber] [int] NULL;

    EXEC('DECLARE @ind INT 
    SET @ind = 0 
    UPDATE [dbo].[Widgets]
    SET @ind = [IndexNumber] = @ind + 1;');

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ALTER COLUMN [IndexNumber] [int] NOT NULL;
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------
Commit tran
Print 'Upgrade completed'
```

The reason why the original code doesn't work because it tries to *compile* the entire batch before running it - the compilation fails and so it never even starts the transaction, let along alters the table.

Comment: Looks good. Will using an exec cause the statement to be performed outside the transaction or after it? As for your earlier comment about the actual upgrade not working, it might be the case but this is my only lead at the moment.

Comment: @Nenotlep - no, it'll still be within the same transaction.

Comment: This actually seems like the easiest way to go, which for me is pretty much synonymous with the best. Using this instead of GO I don't have to reorder my labels or rethink my script flow. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a new column and use it within the same batch. You need to insert `GO` between adding a column and using it.

Transaction is still ok (you can test that by changing `Commit tran` to `rollback tran` to see no changes were committed).

```
Print 'Beginning Upgrade'
Begin Transaction
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------
    USE [MyDatabase];

    /* Widgets now can be ordered and the order can be modified */
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ADD [IndexNumber] [int] NULL;

    GO

    DECLARE @ind INT 
    SET @ind = 0 
    UPDATE [dbo].[Widgets]
    SET @ind = [IndexNumber] = @ind + 1;

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ALTER COLUMN [IndexNumber] [int] NOT NULL;
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------
Commit tran
Print 'Upgrade completed'
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution. The only issue is that after beginning the transaction, I do a version check and if it fails, I do a `GOTO Failover;`. The failover label is actually declared a little after `Commit tran`, so the GOTO is in a different batch than the declaration --> fail. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Can you move that label before GOTO?

Comment: It might be difficult.. Here is a larger paste of the upgrade script: http://pastebin.com/FwKimM66

Comment: I'm trying this within a `BEGIN TRY / END TRY` block, and the inclusion of `GO` throws syntax errors on the `TRY` of the end statement (and the semicolon of a random line in the middle)...so confused

Comment: Please, be aware that you will be not able to `ROLLBACK` transaction with `GO` inside. `TRY`/`CATCH` will not work with `GO`. As **result** - there is no real `TRANSACTION` in this example. If you fail after `GO` - everything before `GO` will be saved in DB and not reverted because you have only `COMMIT TRANSACTION` here.

Answer (score 1):

Call 'go' after you alter table

```
USE [MyDatabase];

  /* Widgets now can be ordered and the order can be modified */
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ADD [IndexNumber] [int] NULL;
GO

BEGIN TRAN;
    DECLARE @ind INT 
    SET @ind = 0 
    UPDATE [dbo].[Widgets]
    SET @ind = [IndexNumber] = @ind + 1;

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Widgets] ALTER COLUMN [IndexNumber] [int] NOT NULL;
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------
COMMIT TRAN;
```