# Safely add a non-null column to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
              WHERE Name = N'MyColumn' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[MySchema].[MyTable]'))
    ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable] 
        ADD [MyColumn] VARCHAR(10) NULL
GO

UPDATE [MySchema].[MyTable] 
SET [MyColumn] = 'ValueForExistingData' 
WHERE [MyColumn] IS NULL

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable] 
    ALTER COLUMN [MyColumn] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
```

What kind of locking / transaction isolation level is required to ensure that no new rows are inserted in between the `UPDATE` and `ALTER COLUMN` statements? This is to prevent the `ALTER COLUMN` statement from failing because of a `NULL` value in `MyColumn` in the newly inserted row.

Is there a better alternative to `GO` to ensure `ADD [MyColumn]` completes before `SET [MyColumn]` ?

Comment: check this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443262/add-column-to-table-and-then-update-it-inside-transaction

Comment: use try catch with go to and label statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following syntax:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable] 
        ADD [MyColumn] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT MyTableDefault DEFAULT 'ValueForExistingData';

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable] 
        DROP CONSTRAINT MyTableDefault;

COMMIT
```

On Enterprise edition SQL Server 2012+ both statements will be metadata only operations, so you will not have to update all data pages and the whole operation will take milliseconds.

Comment: It depends on edition of SQL Server whether the first one is metadata only. They need to be using Enterprise Edition for on prem version. Regardless it still does what they ask

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Default constrain to ensure that all existing column has a value for existing data.

Then drop the default constrain to force new lines to have an entered value.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
              WHERE Name = N'MyColumn' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[MySchema].[MyTable]'))
    ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable] 
        ADD [MyColumn] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ValueForExistingData';
GO

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[MyTable] 
ALTER COLUMN [MyColumn] DROP DEFAULT;
GO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql