# SQL how can I update a table after I just altered the column that I am trying to update?

Tags: sql

I need to set my column consent in the same file that I am creating it in. The problem is that I get an error saying that consent is an invalid column name meaning it isn't going to run unless the altered statement has run and added the column to the table first. Is there anything I could do to get my altered statement to run first adding the consent column to the table than running my updated statement? Again I need to run this in the same file together.

```
  USE [Elearn2]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'UserMetaData' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Consent')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE UserMetaData 
            ADD Consent BIT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            [CreatedAt] [datetime2]  NULL,
        [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [UpdatedAt] [datetime2] NULL,
        [UpdatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL;
        END  
        
        UPDATE UserMetaData 
SET Consent = 0
WHERE Consent IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE UserMetaData
ALTER COLUMN Consent BIT NOT NULL;

UPDATE UserMetaData 
SET [CreatedBy] = ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
WHERE [CreatedBy] IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE UserMetaData
ALTER COLUMN [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL;
UPDATE UserMetaData 
SET [UpdatedBy] = ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
WHERE [UpdatedBy] IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE UserMetaData
ALTER COLUMN [UpdatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL;

UPDATE UserMetaData 
SET [CreatedAt] = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'
WHERE [CreatedAt] IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE UserMetaData
ALTER COLUMN [CreatedAt] [datetime2] NOT NULL;

UPDATE UserMetaData 
SET [UpdatedAt] = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'
WHERE [UpdatedAt] IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE UserMetaData
ALTER COLUMN [UpdatedAt] [datetime2] NOT NULL;

        DECLARE @ModDate NVARCHAR(max)
    
        SET @ModDate = '
    
        CREATE TRIGGER ModDate 
        ON UserMetaData
        AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE X 
        SET [UpdatedAt] = GETDATE()
        FROM UserMetaData X
        JOIN inserted i ON X.[UserId] = i.[UserId] 
    END'
    EXECUTE (@ModDate)
```

Comment: How are you running the file?  Try putting lines with 'GO' between the statements

Comment: see this answer, looks like they are doing the same thing and using Jason's suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443262/add-column-to-table-and-then-update-it-inside-transaction

Comment: @JasonGoemaat  My MAN! That worked thank you